# await work in chrome console without async wrapper

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-devtools

I've read the MDN definition for await which is : 
"The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function."
which works in the editor. However in the chrome console 
I wrote an async function then in the global execution I typed await functionName and that works perfectly without needing to the async function wrapper, **edit: is that supported in the chrome's console just ?**

```
const asyncGreeting = async () => 'Greeting'
```

then in the global execution

```
await asyncGreeting()
```

the result was "Greeting"

Comment: So the Chrome REPL is weird. Did you have a question? (I see a question mark in your post, but it follows a statement).

Comment: This feature was added in Chrome 62 https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#await

Comment: As Roland wrote, this works already in the console but not for the normal code execution. However, there is a proposal for that https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await

Comment: I had same question and this quetsion helps. + 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) is a proposed addition to ECMAScript.

Chrome [added support for it](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#await) to the dev tools.

Hence you can see it working in your test.