# JavaScript, Promise {<pending>}

Tags: javascript, json, promise, async-await, fetch

```
async function db(path){
  const res = await fetch('data.json');
  const data = await res.json();
  return data[path];
}

console.log(db("name"));
```

how can i fix the Promise {pending}
I am trying to get Global Access to my database json file from anywhere in my code is this right way or there is a better way ?

Comment: An `async` function will always return a Promise. Use [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) on the promise returned so you can provide a callback for when the promise resolves (or `.catch()` if the promise reject)

Comment: How are you using the function? The code you've posted is good.

Comment: I am trying to get global access to my json database I cant find any examples if someone knows please give me some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have an async function that returns a promise, but you call it in a not async way. What you should simply do is add an await before your call:

```
async function db(path){
  const res = await fetch('data.json');
  const data = await res.json();
  return data[path];
}

console.log(await db("name"));
```

Comment: ```console.log(await db("name"));``` await should not work here.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed Why?

Comment: "```await``` works only inside async functions" as I know.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed It also works in the global scope in V8. Just open your devtools and write:

var dummyPromiseFunction = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(100), 100);}
);

async function test(path) {
    const data = await dummyPromiseFunction();
    return data;
}

console.log(await test());

Comment: @woXrooX bad formatting in comments on stack overflow. Just paste console.log(await fetch("google.com"))

Comment: Did you try ```console.log(await fetch("google.com"))``` other than console? @AlexandreSenges

Comment: ```Top-level await``` is introduces on chrome dev tool only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57460064/4610740

Comment: @SajeebAhamed Yes that's what I said... `global scope in V8`. If you want to use it in an imported module, which is no specified in the question, just wrap it in an async IIFE such as (async () => {console.log(await db("name"));})();

Answer (score 0):

The return of the function simply returns another promise. So you can modify your function like this-

```
async function db(){
  const res = await fetch('data.json');
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}

db().then(data => console.log(data['name']);
```

**Note:** You should not return anything from a async function. You should do what you want inside the funciton

Comment: It worked thanks! Is this the only way to get global access to my db ? or should i use other way ?

Comment: Async operations should do this way. You can use ```react/vue/angular``` or any other javascript libraries for data reactivity. Where you can set/update data on the availability.