# Dinero JS - Currency Conversion

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am attempting to use the DineroJs library : https://dinerojs.com/module-dinero and using the Currency Conversion method : [https://dinerojs.com/module-dinero#~convert](https://dinerojs.com/module-dinero#%7Econvert)

I am simply attempting to use the provided documentation with the custom rate option. My issue is that I cannot resolve the promise resolved as a variable. No combination of async/await or chaining promises will allow me to assign the currency value as a variable. Here is the code:

```
  const rates = {
  rates: {
    EUR: 0.81162
  }
}

const value = Dinero({ amount: 500 })
  .convert('EUR', {
    endpoint: new Promise(resolve => resolve(rates))
  }).then(dinero => {
    return dinero.getCurrency() // returns 'EUR'
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle errors
  })
```

How do I return the value of "EUR" from this snippet?

If you want to test this easily, use the console on the Dinero site as it has the library enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an await before Dinero, see below.

```
const rates = {
  rates: {
    EUR: 0.81162
  }
}

const value = await Dinero({ amount: 500 })
  .convert('EUR', {
    endpoint: new Promise(resolve => resolve(rates))
  }).then(dinero => {
    return dinero.getCurrency() // returns 'EUR'
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle errors
  })

console.log(value) //prints EUR
```

Comment: Very interesting - I was not aware of this syntax. I have never had to use a top-level await before. Just seems interesting that the docs do not provide this syntax. 

Thank you!

Comment: It's a great feature that has been available in chrome dev tools for a while now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57460064/387285